# maven trick to change package names

Tags: maven, apache-storm

Our project is planning to upgrade storm from 0.10.0 to 1.0.2.

Between these versions, storm has changed all package-names from `backtype` to `org.apache`

Now we use a couple of 3rd party storm dependencies like storm-jms, https://github.com/HolmesNL/kafka-spout etc.

Some of these projects have plans to upgrade soon to 1.0.2 but some do not have it on their roadmap.

So when we upgrade the storm-version in pom.xml, all those 3rd party dependencies begin to cause compilation errors as they do not find `backtype.*` packages anymore.

What is the best strategy to proceed in such a case?

Is there a maven-trick published somewhere to change the package names automatically?

Comment: Are you talking about the groupId of the maven artifact or about the Java package name?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your pom, you can add class relocation (https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/class-relocation.html)

The patterns, that you have to use, are in following class -
https://github.com/apache/storm/blob/master/storm-rename-hack/src/main/java/org/apache/storm/hack/StormShadeRequest.java

Answer (score 0):

From Storm web page (https://storm.apache.org/releases/1.0.0/index.html):

> NOTE
>
> In the latest version, the class packages have been changed from "backtype.storm" to "org.apache.storm" so the topology code compiled with older version won't run on the Storm 1.0.0 just like that. Backward compatibility is available through following configuration
>
> `client.jartransformer.class: "org.apache.storm.hack.StormShadeTransformer"`
>
> You need to add the above config in storm installation if you want to run the code compiled with older versions of storm. The config should be added in the machine you use to submit your topologies.
>
> Refer to https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/STORM-1202 for more details.